# How to use one column's value to classify data into three lines for line graph

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data set where column A is the algorithm, column B is the number of threads and column C is the throughput. I want to draw a line graph with number of threads as x axis and throughput as y axis. I want to draw three lines because I have three algorithms. Then I found I cannot use column one as the grouping parameter. Can anyone help?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY({A2:A, A2:C}, 
 "select Col3,max(Col4) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col3,Col2,Col4 pivot Col1 label Col3'x'")*1, 
 QUERY({A2:A, A2:C}, 
 "select Col3,max(Col4) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col3,Col2,Col4 pivot Col1")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function.

To group terms you would have to feed the already grouped data to the chart builder. Which you can do with the `QUERY` function that uses SQL like language.

```
=QUERY(A1:C10, "select A, avg(B), avg(C) group by A")
```

This is what it might look like in a sheet:

[image]